# Import Maven Projects in Eclipse Indigo. Maven-compiler plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo

In Eclipse Indigo IDE, I try import Maven Project.
And on 3 step I see 2 errors (see screenshot).

Who can explain me, what this errors mean and how I can fix these errors?

[image: Maven-compiler-plugin]

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you choose to resolve all later?

Comment: What happens when you run `mvn clean install package` for your project, in a command window?

Comment: mvn clean install package show me: "BUILD FAILED". And at this moment, I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you open the details of the errors shown for maven-compiler-plugin?
In all likelyhood, you have configured maven-compiler-plugin with some specific details that are not understood/supported by M2E.
M2E tries to support as many plugins as possible but when it does not know what it will do or produce and it does not know when it is appropriate to trigger it, it shows this kind of errors.